# Adding Key and Value inside a list of lists python

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this `[[{'title': 'Line'}], [{'title': 'asd'}]]`. I want to add a new key and value for every list inside of lists.

I have tried this but I'm having an error 'list' object is not a mapping. Any suggestion?

```py
data = [[{'title': 'Line'}], [{'title': 'asd'}]]
titleID = [{'id': 373}, {'id': 374}]
combine = [{**dict_1, **dict_2}
           for dict_1, dict_2 in zip(char_id, data )]
```

the output I want is like this:

```py
[[{'id': 373, 'title': 'Line'}], [{'id': 374, 'title': 'asd'}]]
```

Comment: what's your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `list comphrehension` and unpacking

```
data = [[{'title': 'Line'}], [{'title': 'asd'}]]
titleID = [{'id': 373}, {'id': 374}]
[[{**i[0], **j}] for i,j in zip(data, titleID)]
```

Output

```
[[{'title': 'Line', 'id': 373}], [{'title': 'asd', 'id': 374}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for a one-liner:

```py
[[{**dict_1[0], **dict_2}] for dict_1, dict_2 in zip(data, titleID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the elements of `data` are not dictionaries, but lists.
You can directly unpack nested iterable structures. See [target_list](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target-list) for more details.

```py
data = [[{'title': 'Line'}], [{'title': 'asd'}]]
titleID = [{'id': 373}, {'id': 374}]

print([[{**dict1, **dict2}] for [dict1], dict2 in zip(data, titleID)])
```

will work.
output:

```py
[[{'title': 'Line', 'id': 373}], [{'title': 'asd', 'id': 374}]]
```

And if you are using Python 3.9+, you can use [`|` operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/) for combining dictionaries.

```py
print([[dict1 | dict2] for [dict1], dict2 in zip(data, titleID)])
```